# azure analyis service Processing using .NET Activity in Azure data factory is fail

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

my Requirement is Process Analyis service cube using OnDemand Hdinsight .net Activity, I was following this url -https://learn.microsoft.com/.... now my pipline working fine. I have C# code for processing azure analyis service is working fine with my .exe example. when I put same code in existing .net activity example it fails. below is my source code

-----Source Code------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// ---------------------

using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Runtime;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DataRefresh;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace MyDotNetActivityNS
{
public class MyDotNetActivity : IDotNetActivity
{

/// <summary>
/// Execute method is the only method of IDotNetActivity interface you must implement.
/// In this sample, the method invokes the Calculate method to perform the core logic.
/// </summary>

public IDictionary<string, string=""> Execute(
IEnumerable<linkedservice> linkedServices,
IEnumerable<dataset> datasets,
Activity activity,
IActivityLogger logger)
{
// get extended properties defined in activity JSON definition
// (for example: SliceStart)
DotNetActivity dotNetActivity = (DotNetActivity)activity.TypeProperties;
string sliceStartString = dotNetActivity.ExtendedProperties["SliceStart"];

// to log information, use the logger object
// log all extended properties
IDictionary<string, string=""> extendedProperties = dotNetActivity.ExtendedProperties;
logger.Write("Logging extended properties if any...");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string=""> entry in extendedProperties)
{
logger.Write("<key:{0}> <value:{1}>", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}

// linked service for input and output data stores
// in this example, same storage is used for both input/output
AzureStorageLinkedService inputLinkedService;

// get the input dataset
Dataset inputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset => dataset.Name == activity.Inputs.Single().Name);

// declare variables to hold type properties of input/output datasets
AzureBlobDataset inputTypeProperties, outputTypeProperties;

// get type properties from the dataset object
inputTypeProperties = inputDataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureBlobDataset;

// log linked services passed in linkedServices parameter
// you will see two linked services of type: AzureStorage
// one for input dataset and the other for output dataset
foreach (LinkedService ls in linkedServices)
logger.Write("linkedService.Name {0}", ls.Name);

// get the first Azure Storate linked service from linkedServices object
// using First method instead of Single since we are using the same
// Azure Storage linked service for input and output.
inputLinkedService = linkedServices.First(
linkedService =>
linkedService.Name ==
inputDataset.Properties.LinkedServiceName).Properties.TypeProperties
as AzureStorageLinkedService;

// get the connection string in the linked service
string connectionString = inputLinkedService.ConnectionString;

// get the folder path from the input dataset definition
string folderPath = GetFolderPath(inputDataset);
string output = string.Empty; // for use later.

// create storage client for input. Pass the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount inputStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient inputClient = inputStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// initialize the continuation token before using it in the do-while loop.
BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
do
{ // get the list of input blobs from the input storage client object.
BlobResultSegment blobList = inputClient.ListBlobsSegmented(folderPath,
true,
BlobListingDetails.Metadata,
null,
continuationToken,
null,
null);

// Calculate method returns the number of occurrences of
// the search term (“Microsoft”) in each blob associated
// with the data slice. definition of the method is shown in the next step.

output = Calculate(blobList, logger, folderPath, ref continuationToken, "Microsoft");

} while (continuationToken != null);

// get the output dataset using the name of the dataset matched to a name in the Activity output collection.
Dataset outputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset => dataset.Name == activity.Outputs.Single().Name);

// get type properties for the output dataset
outputTypeProperties = outputDataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureBlobDataset;

//Cube Processing

string serverName = @"asazure://XXXXX.asazure.win...";
string databaseName = "DDDDDDDDD";
// QueryBinding oQueryBinding;
string UserId = "a.com";
string Password = "XXXXXXXX";
string ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + serverName + ";User ID=" + UserId + ";Password=" + Password + "; Persist Security Info=True; Impersonation Level=Impersonate;";
// string ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source="+serverName+ ";Initial Catalog="+ databaseName + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false";

Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
server.Connect(ConnectionString);
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Database db = server.Databases[databaseName];

db.Model.RequestRefresh(RefreshType.Full);
db.Model.SaveChanges();

//End Cube Processing

// get the folder path from the output dataset definition
folderPath = GetFolderPath(outputDataset);

// log the output folder path
logger.Write("Writing blob to the folder: {0}", folderPath);

// create a storage object for the output blob.
CloudStorageAccount outputStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
// write the name of the file.
Uri outputBlobUri = new Uri(outputStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint, folderPath + "/" + GetFileName(outputDataset));

// log the output file name
logger.Write("output blob URI: {0}", outputBlobUri.ToString());

// create a blob and upload the output text.
CloudBlockBlob outputBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(outputBlobUri, outputStorageAccount.Credentials);
logger.Write("Writing {0} to the output blob", output);
//outputBlob.UploadText(output);

// The dictionary can be used to chain custom activities together in the future.
// This feature is not implemented yet, so just return an empty dictionary.

return new Dictionary<string, string="">();
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the folderPath value from the input/output dataset.
/// </summary>

private static string GetFolderPath(Dataset dataArtifact)
{
if (dataArtifact == null || dataArtifact.Properties == null)
{
return null;
}

// get type properties of the dataset
AzureBlobDataset blobDataset = dataArtifact.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureBlobDataset;
if (blobDataset == null)
{
return null;
}

// return the folder path found in the type properties
return blobDataset.FolderPath;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the fileName value from the input/output dataset.
/// </summary>

private static string GetFileName(Dataset dataArtifact)
{
if (dataArtifact == null || dataArtifact.Properties == null)
{
return null;
}

// get type properties of the dataset
AzureBlobDataset blobDataset = dataArtifact.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureBlobDataset;
if (blobDataset == null)
{
return null;
}

// return the blob/file name in the type properties
return blobDataset.FileName;
}

/// <summary>
/// Iterates through each blob (file) in the folder, counts the number of instances of search term in the file,
/// and prepares the output text that is written to the output blob.
/// </summary>

public static string Calculate(BlobResultSegment Bresult, IActivityLogger logger, string folderPath, ref BlobContinuationToken token, string searchTerm)
{
string output = string.Empty;
logger.Write("number of blobs found: {0}", Bresult.Results.Count<ilistblobitem>());
foreach (IListBlobItem listBlobItem in Bresult.Results)
{
CloudBlockBlob inputBlob = listBlobItem as CloudBlockBlob;
if ((inputBlob != null) && (inputBlob.Name.IndexOf("$$$.$$$") == -1))
{
string blobText = inputBlob.DownloadText(Encoding.ASCII, null, null, null);
logger.Write("input blob text: {0}", blobText);
string[] source = blobText.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var matchQuery = from word in source
where word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant()
select word;
int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
output += string.Format("{0} occurrences(s) of the search term \"{1}\" were found in the file {2}.\r\n", wordCount, searchTerm, inputBlob.Name);
}
}
return output;
}
}
}
```

**Error**

> Unknown error in module: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: The connection string is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.GetInstancePort(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo) --- End

Comment: any progress on this?